# Application not responding when GC runs

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

Our application runs 24*7 with heavy user load, recnlty we started having issues with system performance, application not responding, we had to restart JVM to get it back online while investigating we found out that JVM runs GC and at that time application slows down, sometime not even responding,
 Below is our stats for GC during that time.
[GC Heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2WX5.png)
[GC Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCWoO.png)

Looking at this data, is there any recommendations on what to look for or if any JVM configuration needs to be corrected?

Java Version is 7, GC settings are #jvm -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/opt/Server/logs/gclog.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Xms4096M -Xmx6144M -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:ErrorFile=./log/error.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=./log/heap_dump.hprof –

Comment: What's your environment, GC settings and the algorithm used, Java version, etc.

Comment: Java Version is 7, GC settings are  #jvm


-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xloggc:/opt/Server/logs/gclog.log

-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-Xms4096M
-Xmx6144M
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-XX:ErrorFile=./log/error.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=./log/heap_dump.hprof

Comment: Apparently, you are low on memory and have told the JVM to continue, even if reclaiming the next tiny bit of free memory takes a long time (`-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`). You should check whether you have memory leaks in your application. If not, the only solution is to give it more memory.